# Invert y axis on actual data instead of just on the plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, geometry

I have some locations of features that are represented in pixel coordinate space (ie. (0,0) is in the top left corner of the image, and the y axis increases downwards and the x axis increases rightwards).

When I plot these locations in Matplotlib (which by default uses the positive x and positive y quadrant of a cartesian plane) I always run the command

```
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

so that the locations of the features *look* right in the plot.

However, I would like to apply this transformation to the image points themselves, not just in the visualization.

Comment: Show your data.

Comment: a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3) …. np.flipud(a) …. is this what you mean?

Comment: @NaN kind of but the problem with flipud is that an image point that was originally on the top right of the image would end up on the bottom right inside of on the bottom left

Comment: @Carpetfizz, if you want '0' in the above on the bottom right, then np.fliplr(np.flipud(a)) works too.... it works for text as well a0

array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['d', 'e', 'f'],
       ['g', 'h', 'i']], dtype='<U1')

np.fliplr(np.flipud(a0)) …   
array([['i', 'h', 'g'],
       ['f', 'e', 'd'],
       ['c', 'b', 'a']], dtype='<U1')

Answer (score 3):

One can invert all y values by subtracting them from its maximum so that one can then plot it without inverting y axis in matplotlib.

```
y = max(y) - y
```

The plot result will remain the same.

Comment: One must still be advised not to do that as information is lost in this data manipulation.

Comment: Why do you say information is lost? Statistical test will still show same results, though in opposite direction.